# Alteração de lista a partir de uma importação de excel Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

O sistema pode gerar um arquivo excel onde se encontram todos os produtos de um estoque serializados. O que gostaria é que quando esse arquivo for importado de volta que todas alterações feitas nele sejam aplicadas dentro do sistema. Segue exemplo minimo verificável do que consegui fazer até agora

```
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class MinimoVerificavel
{
    public class Products
    {
        private int code;
        private String name;
        private float cost;
        private float price;
        private float netProfit;

        public int getCode()
        {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(int code)
        {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public float getCost()
        {
            return cost;
        }

        public void setCost(float cost)
        {
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public float getPrice()
        {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(float price)
        {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public float getNetProfit()
        {
            return netProfit;
        }

        public void setNetProfit(float netProfit)
        {
            this.netProfit = netProfit;
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public interface Dao<P>
    {
        public void change(P obj) throws Exception;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class Change implements Dao<Products>
    {
        private List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void change(Products obj) throws Exception
        {
            int code = obj.getCode();

            for (Products search : productsList)
            {
                if (search.getCode() == code)
                {
                    search.setName(obj.getName());
                    search.setCost(obj.getCost());
                    search.setPrice(obj.getPrice());
                    search.setNetProfit(obj.getNetProfit());

                    productsList.add(search);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class ModelTableProduts extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();

        public ModelTableProduts(List<Products> list)
        {
            products = list;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column)
        {
            switch (column)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Cod";
                case 1:
                    return "Nome";
                case 2:
                    return "Custo";
                case 3:
                    return "Preço";
                case 4:
                    return "Lucro";
            }
            return super.getColumnName(column);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return products.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
        {
            Products p = products.get(row);
            switch (column)
            {
                case 0:
                    return p.getCode();
                case 1:
                    return p.getName();
                case 2:
                    return p.getCost();
                case 3:
                    return p.getPrice();
                case 4:
                    return p.getNetProfit();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class FrameMinimo extends JFrame
    {
        // Menu
        private JMenuBar menuBar;
        private JMenu menu;
        private JMenuItem exp;
        private JMenuItem imp;

        // Cod
        private Label lblCode;
        private JFormattedTextField ftCode;

        // Name
        private JLabel lblName;
        private JTextField txtName;

        // Cost
        private JLabel lblCost;
        private JFormattedTextField ftCost;

        // Price
        private JLabel lblPrice;
        private JFormattedTextField ftPrice;

        // Net profit
        private JLabel lblNetProfit;
        private JFormattedTextField ftNetProfit;

        // table
        private JTable table;
        private JScrollPane scroll;

        // List
        private List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

        // DAO
        private Dao<Products> dao = new Change();

        public FrameMinimo()
        {
            components();
            events();
            addProduct();
            buildTable();
        }

        private void components()
        {
            setTitle("Importar Excel e alterar");
            setSize(655, 300);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setLayout(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // Menu
            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.setFont(getFont());
            setJMenuBar(menuBar);

            menu = new JMenu("Menu");
            menu.setFont(getFont());
            menuBar.add(menu);

            exp = new JMenuItem("Exportar");
            exp.setFont(getFont());
            menu.add(exp);

            imp = new JMenuItem("Importar");
            imp.setFont(getFont());
            menu.add(imp);

            // cod
            lblCode = new Label("Cod");
            lblCode.setFont(getFont());
            lblCode.setSize(50, 25);
            lblCode.setLocation(10, 10);
            add(lblCode);
            ftCode = new JFormattedTextField();
            ftCode.setFont(getFont());
            ftCode.setSize(50, 25);
            ftCode.setLocation(10, lblCode.getY() + lblCode.getHeight());
            ftCode.setEditable(false);
            add(ftCode);

            // Name
            lblName = new JLabel("Nome");
            lblName.setFont(getFont());
            lblName.setSize(50, 25);
            lblName.setLocation(10, ftCode.getY() + ftCode.getHeight());
            add(lblName);
            txtName = new JTextField();
            txtName.setFont(getFont());
            txtName.setSize(300, 25);
            txtName.setLocation(10, lblName.getY() + lblName.getHeight());
            txtName.setEditable(false);
            add(txtName);

            // Cost
            lblCost = new JLabel("Custo");
            lblCost.setFont(getFont());
            lblCost.setSize(50, 25);
            lblCost.setLocation(txtName.getX() + txtName.getWidth() + 10, ftCode.getY() + ftCode.getHeight());
            add(lblCost);
            ftCost = new JFormattedTextField();
            ftCost.setFont(getFont());
            ftCost.setSize(100, 25);
            ftCost.setLocation(txtName.getX() + txtName.getWidth() + 10, lblCost.getY() + lblCost.getHeight());
            ftCost.setEditable(false);
            add(ftCost);

            // Price
            lblPrice = new JLabel("Preço");
            lblPrice.setFont(getFont());
            lblPrice.setSize(50, 25);
            lblPrice.setLocation(ftCost.getX() + ftCost.getWidth() + 10, ftCode.getY() + ftCode.getHeight());
            add(lblPrice);
            ftPrice = new JFormattedTextField();
            ftPrice.setFont(getFont());
            ftPrice.setSize(100, 25);
            ftPrice.setLocation(ftCost.getX() + ftCost.getWidth() + 10, lblPrice.getY() + lblPrice.getHeight());
            ftPrice.setEditable(false);
            add(ftPrice);

            // Net profit
            lblNetProfit = new JLabel("Lucro liquido");
            lblNetProfit.setFont(getFont());
            lblNetProfit.setSize(100, 25);
            lblNetProfit.setLocation(ftPrice.getX() + ftPrice.getWidth() + 10, ftCode.getY() + ftCode.getHeight());
            add(lblNetProfit);
            ftNetProfit = new JFormattedTextField();
            ftNetProfit.setFont(getFont());
            ftNetProfit.setSize(100, 25);
            ftNetProfit.setLocation(ftPrice.getX() + ftPrice.getWidth() + 10, lblNetProfit.getY() + lblNetProfit.getHeight());
            ftNetProfit.setEditable(false);
            add(ftNetProfit);

            // Table
            table = new JTable();
            scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            scroll.setSize(631, 103);
            scroll.setLocation(10, txtName.getY() + txtName.getHeight() + 5);
            add(scroll);

        }

        private void buildTable()
        {
            ModelTableProduts modelTableProduts = new ModelTableProduts(productsList);
            table.setModel(modelTableProduts);
        }

        private void exp()
        {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Estoque");
            File file = new File("Estoque.xls");
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

            // Chooser properties
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Exportar para XLS");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            chooser.setFileFilter(null);

            chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
            {
                @Override
                public String getDescription()
                {
                    return "XLS File";
                }

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File f)
                {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("xls");
                }
            });

            int action = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

            if (action == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String fileString = file.toString();

                if (fileString.toLowerCase().endsWith("xls") == false)
                {
                    fileString += ".xls";
                    file = new File(fileString);
                }
            }

            int index = 0;

            for (Products products : productsList)
            {
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(index);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(products.getCode());
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(products.getName());
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(products.getCost());
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(products.getPrice());
                row.createCell(4).setCellValue(products.getNetProfit());

                index++;
            }

            try
            {
                workbook.write(file);
                workbook.close();

                System.out.println("Exportado!");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void imp() throws IOException
        {

            File file = null;
            Products sameProduct = null;

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Importar Arquivos XLS");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            chooser.setFileFilter(null);

            int showOpenDialog = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser.getParent()); // Stores user choice

            if (showOpenDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // Checks the user's choice
            {
                file = chooser.getSelectedFile(); // Get the file way if approved
            }

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); // Points to an instance of the file

            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); // Passing FIS to workbook representation

            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Pick the page to be used

            // TODO
            Products product = sameProduct;

            Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) iterator.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    // FIXME
                }
            }

            try
            {
                dao.change(product); // Correct?
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void addProduct()
        {
            Products p1 = new Products();
            p1.setCode(1);
            p1.setName("Teste 1");
            p1.setCost(50);
            p1.setPrice(100);
            p1.setNetProfit(50);
            productsList.add(p1);

            Products p2 = new Products();
            p2.setCode(2);
            p2.setName("Teste 2");
            p2.setCost(50);
            p2.setPrice(100);
            p2.setNetProfit(50);
            productsList.add(p2);

            Products p3 = new Products();
            p3.setCode(3);
            p3.setName("Teste 3");
            p3.setCost(50);
            p3.setPrice(100);
            p3.setNetProfit(50);
            productsList.add(p3);

            Products p4 = new Products();
            p4.setCode(4);
            p4.setName("Teste 4");
            p4.setCost(50);
            p4.setPrice(100);
            p4.setNetProfit(50);
            productsList.add(p4);

            Products p5 = new Products();
            p5.setCode(5);
            p5.setName("Teste 5");
            p5.setCost(50);
            p5.setPrice(100);
            p5.setNetProfit(50);
            productsList.add(p5);
        }

        private void events()
        {
            exp.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    exp();
                }
            });

            imp.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        imp();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MinimoVerificavel mv = new MinimoVerificavel();
        FrameMinimo fm = mv.new FrameMinimo();
        fm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer apenas carregar a lista de produtos? Ou você quer que o mesmo produto alterado na planilha também seja atualizado no banco?

Comment: Quero que o mesmo ou vários produtos alterados na tabela sejam alterados também no programa quando importa-lo de volta. Que no caso não estou usando banco e sim serializador que por sua vez usa o método change para alterar tudo relacionado a produtos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que não vale a pena carregar os dados da planilha e verificar quais foram alterados. Você pode simplesmente substituir os dados do sistema pelos dados oriundos da planilha. Essa abordagem será muito mais rápida. É interessante colocar esses dados em uma mapa, porque depois você pode acessar muito mais rápido os produtos que deseja através do código do produto. Para utilizar o mapa é necessário implementar os métodos `hashCode` e `equals`.

Código que carrega os produtos:

```
try (
            InputStream inputStream = ReadExcelFormula.class.getResourceAsStream("teste.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        ) {
            Map<Integer, Products> productsMap = new HashMap<>();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            for(Row row : sheet) {
                Products product = new Products();
                product.setCode(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue()).intValue());
                product.setName(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                product.setCost(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue()).floatValue());
                product.setPrice(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue()).floatValue());
                product.setNetProfit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()).floatValue());

                productsMap.put(product.getCode(), product);
            }
        }
```

Se ainda assim desejar fazer essa atualização, o seguinte procedimento poderá ser realizado:

1. Carregar os dados em um mapa.
2. Iterar os produtos antigos.
3. Buscar os produtos carregados da planilha através do código do produto.
4. Verificar se os dados foram alterados através do método hashCode. Para isso o méotodo hashCode precisa levar em consideração todos os atributos da classe.
5. Se o hashCode não for igual, atualizar os dados através de um método que recebe o produto atualizado.

Método hashCode:

```
public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + code;
        result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(cost);
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(netProfit);
        result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(price);
        return result;
    }
```

Método para atualizar o produto (esse método deve estar na própria classe Products):

```
public void updateValues(Products updatedProduct) {
        this.name = updatedProduct.name;
        this.cost = updatedProduct.cost;
        this.price = updatedProduct.price;
        this.netProfit = updatedProduct.netProfit;
    }
```

Trecho que itera os produtos antigos, busca os novos e atualiza os valores:

```
List<Products> oldProducts = getOldProducts();
            for (Products oldProduct : oldProducts) {
                Products updatedProduct = productsMap.get(oldProduct.getCode());
                if (oldProduct.hashCode() != updatedProduct.hashCode()) {
                    oldProduct.updateValues(updatedProduct);
                }
            }
```